# How to disable adding of line breaks in CLion at all?

Tags: c++, clion, code-formatting

`CLion` is breaking my code formatting by unknown reason like this:

[image]

I don't have a wish to waste time investigating, how is it happening.

Is it possible to generally prohibit it from wrapping any line wothout direct order from a human (me)?

Answer (score 0):

`Settings - Editor - Code Style - C/C++ - Wrapping and braces`. I think you can set a huge limit to "Hard wrap at" and disable "Wrap on typing". In case of this example, also check out "Function declaration parameters" in the same window.